# My HTML + CSS site is showing a blank space on right and bottom of the screen while the margin is 0 on both bottom and right

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I've removed margin from all body sides. But as you can see the right margin is still there(in white). I've tried to set my navbar and front margin to 0 as well but nothing is working.
The html and css code is provided below. I'm creating this website as a sample for my portfolio but there is a blank space on the right side and also on the bottom. I have no idea what is causing the space. I have tried changing all the margins to 0 and use only paddings but nothing is helping. I have tried to open the file in different browsers too but nothing. I'm new to coding and also new to stackoverflow. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Below is my css:

```
body {
margin: 0 0;
padding: 0 0;
}




                            /********************Navbar*************/

.navbar
{
background-color: #0f3057;
padding: 20px 100px 10px;

}



.nav-item {
padding: 0 10px;
font-size: 1rem;
font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
}

.nav-name {
font-family: 'Antic Didone', serif;
font-size: 2rem;
}



/**************************************************Front*************************************/




.title-img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.img-div {
padding: 50px 30px 50px 100px;
}


#Front-pg {
background-color: #00587a;
}


.txt-div {
padding: 70px 0 0 0;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Antic Didone', serif;
font-size: 4rem;
}

.p1 {
line-height: 2rem;
padding-top: 30px;
font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
}

.p2 {
line-height: 2rem;
font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
}



                     /***********************************Timing*****************************/

#Timing {
  background-color: #e7e7de;
}

.timing {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}


.timing-photo {
  width: 950px;
  height: 500px
}



               /************************************* Price *******************************************/

#Price {
  background-color: #e7e7de;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Pricehead {
  font-family: 'Antic Didone', serif;
}

.Menu {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;

}









              /**************************************** mobile view ***********************************/



              @media (max-width: 1020px) {

              .title-img {
              width: 450px;
              height: 225px;
              }

              #Front-pg {
              text-align: center;
              }

              }
```

Below is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ABC Saloon</title>
  </head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


    <!-- Bootscrap -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antic+Didone&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Didact+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <body>

       <section id="title">


         <!-- Nav Bar -->
         <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
             <a class="navbar-brand nav-name" href=""><i>ABC Saloon</i></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
             <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Gallery</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
         </nav>

       </section>


         <!-- Front Page-->

       <section id="Front-pg">


       <div class="row">

       <div class="col-lg-6 img-div">
         <img class="title-img" src="images/1265.jpg" alt="Saloon">
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6 txt-div">
         <h1><i>ABC Hair Saloon</i> </h1>
         <p class="p1">We're here to listen, educate and advise you on
           what will work best for <br>you and your new look</p>
         <br>
         <p class="p2">Founded in 2000, AR Hair Salon 356 has grown to be the number one <br>Hair Salon in New York, committed to giving you the look you’ve <br>
            always wanted. We have an extensive selection of services to choose
            <br> from so you can get exactly what you need. Swing by and see how
            <br> we can help today!</p>

       </div>
    </div>


       </section>


<section id="Timing">

  <div class="timing">
 <img class="timing-photo" src="images/timg.png" alt="timing">
  </div>

</section>


<section id="Price">

  <h1 class="Pricehead"> <i>Price List</i> </h1>

  <div class="Menu">
    

  </div>

</section>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Besides that your first link under fonts does not close this fiddle doesnt show any red. https://jsfiddle.net/wmg2bp31/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking but I checked it and the problem comes from the bootstrap you have.

The Class 'row' you put under the section of Front-pg is giving you

```
margin-right: -15px
margin-left: -15px;
```

You can overwrite this one by adding a class row in your own CSS file:

```
.row{
   margin: 0;
 }
```

Just make sure that the CSS file you have is below the bootstrap stylesheet when linking the CSS in the HTML

Comment: Thanks, Mar. But the bottom margin is still there. The right margin is removed but there's still some margin at the bottom of the body. What should I do to remove that

Comment: So bootstrap h1 has a bottom-margin of 0.5rem. so just simply overwrite this by adding margin: 0 on your heading.
So to clarify this, every browser or framework (like bootstrap) has its own default styling that's why some CSS styling doesn't work as you want to. So read the documentation of the framework you use or use this [CSS Reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove the default style before adding your own styling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the div with the class of `row`. if you take a look in `_grid.scss` file, you will find a rule-set for the class `row`. it contains `margin-right: -15px;` .

you just need to remove that margin.

to do that, you can override the margin property but you have to put in mind some roles such as selector-specificity and the place of your code.

the easiest way is to just insert this rule-set **after the rule-set that you want to override** Whether below it or in a file that is included after the `_grid.scss` file.

```
.row {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body has 0 margin and no padding, just make sure the children are limited by that (body width):

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

}

overflow-x will limit overflowing on the x direction.